# Jade: How i can write part of code, without changing?

Tags: pug

I have

```
input(name="title", #newtitle)
```

I got

```
input name="title" #newtitle="#newtitle"
```

I need

```
input name="title" #newtitle
```

Comment: Why you downvote my question?

Comment: Have you reviewed the pug documentation on attributes?
https://pugjs.org/language/attributes.html

Comment: You should disable check unknown HTML tag attributes in yours IDE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should disable check unknown HTML tag attributes in yours IDE.

Answer (score -1):

In pug id and class are not in between () so you can either do :

`input#newtitle(name="title")`

or

`input(name="title")#newtitle`

both should work actually (i usually use the first one)

If you want to add more classes/id you can do this :

`input#newtitle#anotherId.firstClass.secondClass(name="title")`

Comment: It is not "id". If I need id, i could wrote "id='element' " at last string.

Comment: so what is it then ? a variable from express that you want to put as default value for your input ?

Comment: No, it is a label.

Comment: I don't get what you want to do ? what is this label for ? (I suppose it's not a label tag thought)